# Toroid with uniform magnetization

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations

I can't understand the following problem:

> Consider a toroid of internal dimension ***R*** and external dimension ***R+2a*** formed by material
> magnetized with a uniform magnetization ***M*** over its section and directed tangentially to the torus (see
> Fig. 4). Determine the behavior of the fields ***B*** and ***H*** in the material.
> (Optional: Also get the value of such
> fields in the presence of a thin transverse cut of thickness ***d***)

[image]

Since there is no free current, wouldn't the circuitation of ***H*** over a circle inside the toroid give us that ***H*** is equal to zero?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct. So H, which is orthoradial by symmetry, is zero everywhere. Then, with the definition of H, it's over!

Hope it can help and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

Not just there is no free current, think of any permanent magnet, there are no effective poles either because of the symmetry.